# Django: Aggregate (sum) of a field on two different set of data in a single query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I am using Django 1.6.
My Model looks something like:

```
Class Transaction(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0.00)
```

I have few transactions, few of which are credit and other are debit (determined by type column). I need to check the balance of all transaction i.e., (debit - credit)

Currently, I could do that using 2 queries as below:

```
debit_amount=Transaction.objects.fitler(type='D').aggregate(debit_amount=Sum('amount'))['debit_amount']
credit_amount=Transaction.objects.fitler(type='C').aggregate(credit_amount=Sum('amount'))['credit_amount']
balance = debit_amount - credit_amount
```

I am looking something like:

```
Transaction.objects.aggregate(credit=Sum('amount', filter=Q(type='C')), debit=Sum('amount', filter=Q(type='D')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import *
result = Transaction.objects.aggregate(
    credit=Sum(Case(
        When(Q(tye='C'), then=F('amount')),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
        default=0
    )),
    debit=Sum(Case(
        When(Q(tye='D'), then=F('amount')),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
        default=0
    )),
)

balance = result['debit'] - result['credit']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in django 2.0 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
totals = Transaction.objects.aggregate(
    credit=Sum('amount', filter=Q(type='C')),
    debit=Sum('amount', filter=Q(type='D'))
)
total = totals.credits - totals.debit
```